# Optional requirement on where clause in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

The goal is to build a search form that can be entered on multiple field searches. But entering all fields are optional.
What is the equivalent code in LINQ?
Thanks.

```
string str = "";
if(a!="")
    str += "f1 == a";
if(b!="")
    str += " && f2 == b";
if(c!="")
    str += " && f3 == c";

select f1, f2, f3 from p
where str;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from x in p where (x.f1 == a || a == "") && (x.f2 == b || b == "") && (x.f3 == c || c == "") select new { f1 = x.f1, f2 = x.f2, f3 = x.f3 }
```

The or on each search variable makes it ignored when empty string.  I'm assuming you already took care of nulls in a, b, c.

Answer (score 4):

You can build up the query sequentially in the same way, something like this:

```
var query = someData.Items;

if  (a != string.Empty)
    query = query.Where(x => x.f1 == a);

if (b != string.Empty)
    query = query.Where(x => x.f2 == b);
```

…and so on. In the end, you have built a query with only the relevant predicates.

Comment: +1 for actually using LINQ features, and giving an answer that will perform much better than the alternative of having the SQL server/LINQ driver try to optimize out the irrelevant portions (which it usually? does, but not always)